# how to get a value and not the formula

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to obtain the minimum value from a worksheet however when I generate the minimum and place it in a cell, and then extract that value I am getting the entire formula and not the double value in the cell.... what am I doing wrong?  Below is my generate graph method.

Another thing, I would also like to delete the graph after I save it I have tried .delete() but that just threw and error, how do I go about doing that

```
private void GenerateGraph(Worksheet worksheet, int lastRow, int lastColumn, string filename)
        {
            string topLeft = ToCell(0, 0);
            string bottomRight = ToCell(lastRow - 1, lastColumn - 1);



        worksheet.get_Range(ToCell(0, 0), missing).Formula = "Max(B2:" + bottomRight + ")";
        worksheet.get_Range(ToCell(0, 0), missing).FormulaHidden = true;
        worksheet.get_Range(ToCell(0, 0), missing).Calculate();
        Range range = (Range)worksheet.Cells[1,1];

        //
        //here is where my problem is, small is being given the formula from above
        //

        string small = (string)range.Value2;
        double min = Convert.ToDouble(small);
        worksheet.get_Range(ToCell(0,0),missing).Formula = "";

        //Generates the graph
        range = worksheet.get_Range(topLeft, bottomRight);
        ChartObjects Xlchart = (ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(missing);
        ChartObject chart = (ChartObject)Xlchart.Add(20, 160, 600, 500);
        Excel.Chart myChart = chart.Chart;
        myChart.SetSourceData(range, missing);

        //sets the y axis
        Axis axis = (Axis)myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        axis.MinimumScaleIsAuto = true;
        axis.MaximumScaleIsAuto = true;
        axis.HasTitle = true;
        axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Measure (m)";
        axis.CrossesAt = (int)(min-1);

        //sets the x axis
        Axis xAxis = (Axis)myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        xAxis.HasTitle = true;
        xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Position (m)";

        //makes the graph a line graph
        myChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers;

        //titles the graph
        myChart.HasTitle = true;
        myChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Profiles";

        //saves the graph
        myChart.Export(filename, "JPG", missing);

        //
        //here is where I would like to delete the graph
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
Formula = "=Max(B2:" + bottomRight + ")"
```

You were missing the equals sign in the formula.

Comment: That I was, that solves the first half of my problem, now how do I delete the graph from the actual excel file?

Comment: @Bob That's the problem with asking two questions in one. I know the answer to the first, but not the second. You'd be better off editing this question to remove the delete part, and then asking a new question just containing that!